Why do many great Tzaddikim die so young?
Examples:

Chanoch (365)
King Shlomo (55)
King Yoshiyahu (38)
Ramak (48)
The Arizal Hakodesh (38)
Ramchal (39)
Ohr Hachaim Hakodesh (46)
Rebbe Nachman (38)

Why, sometimes, do the greatest of the greats, die so young? Is there any reason given in our sources?
(The list is curated on minimal criteria, and therefore it may be true that not all names will apply to the answer you want to give - that's fine, please give it, all sourced answers welcome. This is an emotional and serious topic, so please, no cynical answers or comments. Just don't.)

Isn’t there the midrash that Hashem lets them “leave the party” first to avoid trouble

“only the good die young”

Do you ask teleologically or causally? Regarding teleology, the question is valid for any person dying young, and those rabbis weren't an exception. Causally, Jewish sages traditionally focused on cultic observance and prayers, instead of the promotion of science and medicine. For millennia, people died young of diseases, infections, bad living conditions, lack of hygiene, violence, and more situations we don't experience nowadays. On the third hand, the age curve of Jewish rabbis was pretty normal and the same proportion died old.

To support @Schmerel's answer: "Generals don't die young" - as it takes time to teach, write works, and get public recognition, we can assume, statistically, that the vast majority of prominent rabbis throughout the ages, died very old. Those who "died relatively young" were an exception in their early proliferation and recognition.

I downvoted the question as "so many" seems to be factually false. Maybe it's worth investing some time in checking statistics - you provide 8 out of, what, 10,000?.

8 is so many. It's not a proportional statement.

Has anyone ever proposed that it is because they have a fiery neshama that burns bright? Akin to a hot, large star that burns its fuel and dies much faster than a cooler, smaller star, lhavdil?

Instead of "many" do you mean "any"?

@DoubleAA no, I mean a lot

So answers can't just give a reason why some might die, but need to specifically address why "a lot" (whatever that means) die?

@DoubleAA the lowest quality, but acceptable answer can give why some might die very young, applicable to the possibility of a high quantity . The highest will give why a lot do, with specifics. I am fishing. I also have cat on lap so can't really comment further for now :)

In general this isn’t true. Gedoley Torah have a MUCH longer life span than the average person. Even though people are rarely regarded as Gedoley Torah when they are younger than sixty they still outlive what is on the actuarial chart for most sixty years old. By many years.  As far as why some die younger it could be it was just their mazal at birth to die young. Of more substance when the Chofetz Chaim’s son in law R’ Hirsh Levinson died young, his wife asked him how is it possible such a Tzadik could die so young. The CC answered that Midas HaDin would have caused the destruction  of half the world. Instead Midas HaDin took  R’ Hirsh Levinson as a misas tzadikim mechaper.

"Gedoley Torah have a MUCH longer life span than the average person." What evidence do you have for this claim?

@DoubleAA nor does it matter? The question doesn't imply that Gedoley Torah have any particular relative life span.

@RabbiKaii then we should edit out the irrelevant falsehood

Look at how many of the recently departed gedoley Torah were over a hundred years old  at their time of death. Compare how old they were in the 1800s or the medieval ages  to what the general life expectancy was at the time was. How many people in the 1930s lived to 95 like the Chofetz Chaim or 110 like Rabbi Shlomo Alfandari?

@DoubleAA lack of proof doesn't mean it's false. I am just interested in the some that die younger, and am looking for answers based on sources. The example with R' Levinson was the kind of thing. Wouldn't mind a bit of explanation though?

@Schmerel the modern charedi world only picks as its leader the oldest guy around so of course they're all old. Just like how the Samaritans pick their Kohein Gadol (הכהן הגדול מאחיו). There are random PhD secular academics who reach 100 too just you don't hear about them and they don't try to still lead their field. Over 15% of living US presidents will be over 100 next month, so I guess you'd conclude US presidents have longer than average lives?

Classic, wikipedia already has lists https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_centenarians_(religious_figures) There's a couple Jews there, but nothing "above average"

The Wikipedia list does not list Rav Schach, Rav Elyasiv, Rav Shteinman, Rav Scheinberg etc . If they were they would far outweigh groups. Particularly  consider how much smaller of a the  number of people and potential leaders in their group is to begin with in comparison to other groups

@Schmerel If they added all the people you know from your field off the top of your head, then there'd be more of your group. And if all the Muslims added only the people they know, there'd be more Muslims. This is textbook bad reasoning https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Availability_bias https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias

@Schmerel And btw the wikipedia page already does list all 4 of those rabbis (search these spellings Shach Eliashiv Shteinman Scheinberg)

I’m very  familiar with the secular Jewish world which is a lot bigger than the frum world. Other than Menachem Mordechai Kaplan I can’t think of a single leader of theirs who lived to be over a hundred in the past hundred years. Without google searching  can you?

@Sch (In virtually all other fields people retire well before they hit 100 and you stop hearing about them. In Charedism the gadol doesn't officially retire, he just 'lets' his shamash do everything in his name.) My first guess is Professor Halivini, but anyway you're missing the point that neither of our memories is statistically significant. The goal is not who can name people sans Google. It's exactly the opposite: how many centenarians the actual data suggests we expect with X% confidence from a population of a certain size? [Edit: apparently Halivini was 'only' 94]

@DoubleAA For what it's worth, the Jewish presence on the list (13/116=11.2%) is disproportionately high (47x the Jewish share of the religious portion of world population)

@ba that's effectively comparing first and third world countries

@DoubleAA Removing Africa and South America from world population, and all secular people from world population, we still get at least 13/110 of list vs. 0.3% of world population, 40x the Jewish share of the rest of the world's religious population. If you have a better method you're welcome to pursue it.

@ba Why are you leaving in Asia?? Not to mention selection bias (the vast majority of the list is chrisitian, probably correlating with who edits english wikipedia). I don't have time, interest or more importantly the relevant data to do a full statistical analysis. I bet if you ask on Skeptics someone already has searched for general correlations between longevity and religion.

The final appendix to Service of the Heart is a letter from Rav Moshe Wolfson ztz”l to a woman who lost a pregnancy. He refers to the kabbalistic concept of the “well of souls,” a repository min hashamayim that contains all the souls that are destined to take bodies on earth. He explains that when a neshama has fulfilled its tachlis on earth, Hashem calls the soul back up, and sometimes this happens quite quickly. Even in such tragic cases, he adds, such short lives bring us closer to Mashiach.
Moed Katan 28a:

Rabbi Ami said: Why was the Torah portion that describes the death of
Miriam juxtaposed to the portion dealing with the red heifer? To tell
you: Just as the red heifer atones for sin, so too, the death of the
righteous atones for sin. Rabbi Elazar said: Why was the Torah portion
that describes the death of Aaron juxtaposed to the portion discussing
the priestly garments? This teaches that just as the priestly garments
atone for sin, so too, the death of the righteous atones for sin.


The Midrash says:

Rabbi Chiya Bar Abba said: The sons of Aaron died the first day of Nisan. Why then does the Torah mention their death in conjunction with the Day of Atonement? It is to teach that just as the Day of Atonement atones, so also the death of the righteous atones [Leviticus Rabbah 20:12].

This will not satisfy everybody.

The Rambam says in the Guide (III.23), in his exposition of Sefer Iyov, that it is necessary for Hashem's justice to be inscrutable in order to give us a correct relationship to Hashem. For if (for instance) life expectancy were always correlated with a person's righteousness, then we would erroneously believe that we understand Hashem's ways, which would be a grave error.

God fudges the data so we can't figure out His ways?  What about His promises in the Torah, given in exchange for observance?  And what is your precise reference?

@MauriceMizrahi Rambam explains (Hil. Teshuvah, ch. 9) that those are not rewards in exchange for observance, but Hashem providing us the means to perform more mitzvos.

@MauriceMizrahi ... I don't think I'd use the analogy of "fudging the data".... maybe more like, "obfuscates the algorithm". But the Rambam isn't saying that he goes out of his way to obfuscate, rather that it's naturally obscure (like trying to imagine the 12th dimension) and very good for us to be aware of our limitations, because that awareness ironically gets us closer to God.
